# Does the GOP actually have a formal 'neutrality policy' that this unnamed RNC official describes?

Tags: united-states, campaign-finance, funding, republican-primary

[This answer to *Why would a former US president's announcement of a reelection bid cut off legal defense funds?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/74690/16047) *in toto:*

> From the July 28, 2022 Yahoo article, by Cheryl Teh, [The RNC has been helping Trump pay his legal bills but will pull the plug once he kicks off his 2024 campaign](https://news.yahoo.com/rnc-helping-trump-pay-legal-071035168.html):
>
> > The Republican National Committee has been helping former President Donald Trump fund his legal battles but would stop if he declares a 2024 run, ABC News reported.
> >
> > The outlet spoke to an unnamed RNC official, who said that payments would dry up once Trump announces he's running for the GOP presidential nomination.
> >
> > **The official attributed this to the GOP's "neutrality policy," which means that the party needs to be impartial to all candidates in the run-up to the presidential primary.**

**Question:** Does the GOP actually have a formal 'neutrality policy' that this unnamed RNC official describes?

I'm wondering if this is established in some bylaws somewhere or if it's perhaps only a "policy of convenience" that arose in response to the reporter's question, or somewhere in between.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Rules of the Republican Party](https://prod-static.gop.com/media/Rules_Of_The_Republican_Party.pdf)

> **RULE NO. 11
>
> Candidate Support**
> (a) The Republican National Committee
> shall not, without the prior written and filed approval of
> all members of the Republican National Committee
> from the state involved, contribute money or in-kind aid
> to any candidate for any public or party office of that
> state, except the nominee of the Republican Party or a
> candidate who is unopposed in the Republican primary
> after the filing deadline for that office.

So if there's a contested primary, the RNC can't provide financial support to any of the candidates.

Whether this counts as "neutrality" is a matter of semantics. It also prohibits the RNC from subsidizing all the candidates equally, which would still be neutral.

Comment: Subsidizing candidates equally would favor the poorest candidates, for whom the amount would be a relatively large fraction of total campaign funds.

Comment: @SpencerJoplin By that logic, not subsidizing any candidates favors the richest candidates, since they don't need the subsidies as much.

Comment: But if you take it to that extreme, you're damned if you do, damned if you don't